# Ubuntu 21.04 crashes with grub-install /dev/sda failed fatal error during install

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 21.04 in ThinkPad X200 via a bootable USB drive and replace the 20.04.2 version. I've made the disk partitions for SWAP, /home and /, etc. as usual. Also, the setup asked for an extra boot area partition, so I added 100Mb. And it crashed towards the end with Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error. Overwriting the earlier config or with another config gave me the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you didn't allocate enough space to your /boot partition. Try allocating more space (I would do at least a gig).

Comment: Most desktops do not need a /boot partition. Was it really asking for a bios_grub partition (1MB unformatted with bios_grub flag)which is required for BIOS boot on newer gpt partitioned drives. Or was it asking for an ESP - efi system partition (FAT32 with esp/boot flags usually 300 to 500MB) which is required for UEFI installs. Do not confuse a /boot partition with either a bios_grub partition nor an ESP.

Comment: I think that it was asking for the GRUB partition. The "/boot" told me that the partition was for the "boot" folder on the root of the drive (where the GRUB bootloader is stored). Remember, in UNIX (and this does include Linux since it's UNIX-based), everything is a file.